# npm run build uglifyjs: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: operator (>)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, uglifyjs, create-react-app

I am trying to optimize **Create-react-app** for production using following command:

`npm run build`

But it is giving me following error:

```
static/js/main.9c091e05.js from UglifyJs
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: operator (>) [./~/http-build-query/index.js:16,0]
```

That might be because of module `http-build-query` but that module is too necessary for my app.

I have also tried `yarn build` and that is also giving me same error.

**EDIT**

I just knew by googling that ES6 syntax is not supported by `npm run build`. So the question is how to build ES6 syntax with `npm run build` ?

Comment: `npm run build`is an npm script described in `package.json`. can you post it ?

Comment: You want me to post package.json ?

Comment: a simple copy-paste of its content

Comment: Please check EDIT in question

Comment: What is on line 16 on `/http-build-query/index.js` ?

Comment: Line 16:   var query = Object.keys(queryData).map(k => {

Comment: You are going to need Babel. Not sure if `create-react-app` ships with Babel as default.

Comment: Basically i am using 3rd party npm module `http-build-query` that is written in ES6 and not compiled to ES2015 before uploading to npm. that is creating this issue.

Comment: Maybe this will help - https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/984

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because the ES6 code in your `node_modules` folder [is not handled](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1125#issuecomment-264158377) by `create-react-app` - it assumes they have done this themselves (which they should).

#### Option 1

Stop using that package, and find a better one.

#### Option 2

Copy the code from the package to your own source files so babel has access to it

#### Option 3

Eject `create-react-app` and customize the webpack config yourself, including a test for the `node_modules` folder (can really hinder your build time)

#### Option 4

Overriding the webpack config from `create-react-app` to accomplish `Option 3` without ejecting. Note this is complicated and `Option 1` or `Option 2` is what you should go for

Example of overriding can be found here: https://daveceddia.com/customize-create-react-app-webpack-without-ejecting/

Comment: I have converted that ES5 module (http-build-query) to ES2015 and it worked. Thanks man.

Comment: This is a lifesaver! A real gem! I went with option 2. Worked like a charm! And the reason/explanation with the link to github issue is really helpful! Thanks! :)